# The best way to verify a zip file function in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have a path library which has a zip function in it, and while writing the unit test, I tried to find the best way to verify that the zip function works correctly.

Can someone please show me the best way to verify that the zip function works correctly ?

The few ways I can think of are:

1. Comparing the md5 of the resultant zip file against a sample zip file
2. Listing out the contents of the zip file and ensuring the content are correct

However, both ways seems a little long winded and I am guessing not exactly idiomatic Elixir. Can someone please show me a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create a directory of test files to zip up in your unit test, zip it up using a trusted utility and get the resulting md5. Then for your unit test, perform the zip function, take the md5, and compare with your verified md5.

Comment: Something like this would suffice too I think:`System.cmd("zip -T <filename>")`

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, there are some parameters that can affect the result of zip processing (like block size). So, unless your purpose is to check exhaustively that your zip process reproduces all or a subset of the zip features, I find more interesting to validate that various files from your system (or/and some random files) can be compresses with your function, and uncompressed outside using different unzip tools, and finally compare that the files are identical to the original. (of course it takes more time, but it can be easily automated).

Concerning the usage of MD5 rather than file comparison, I think that on one hand file comparison is easy to write and in the other hand you need to read the whole file to calculate the MD5, so I don't think it is worth to use this trick to accelerate the comparison - (especially if files are different :o).